# Regular Expression to Group Strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am relatively new with Regular Expressions so please excuse me.

I am currently trying to group each line based on the record line. So, for example, I want all lines proceding the record Line to be grouped into one string, until the next record line. I have been trying to use regular expressions, and I have obtained a result that is very close to what I want, however, there is a newline present at the beginning of the array that I am reading it into.

This is the code I am using to split the data up.

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line;
            line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, @"(?=PA11)");

            List<string> parameterList = new List<string>(parts);

            foreach (string s in parameterList)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }
```

And this is the result looks like this:

```
*newline*
LINE 000001 000001 TEST A B TEST OUTPUT *More Lines*                
LINE 000002 000002 TEST A B TEST OUTPUT *More Lines*
```

If anyone can tell me what it is I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like it's not inserting a *newline* but a *blank entry*.  Your regex matches the very beginning of the input because the first line starts with `PA11`, and it doesn't consume any characters, so the first item in the `parts` array is an empty string.  You should be able to prevent that by forcing the regex to consume some characters, such as the newline preceding the `PA11` line:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, @"[\r\n]+(?=PA11)");
```

...or by making sure it doesn't match *unless* there's a newline before `PA11`:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, @"(?<=[\r\n])(?=PA11)");
```

Comment: I tried the first Regex statement and it appears to be working correctly. I just realized that I left out some important information. There are a 3 header lines before any of the PA11 fields, but this does not seem to affecting the statement you gave me. The only issue I have to resolve is that there is 1 extra newline at the end of the the file once I put the file back together after editing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the excessive comments, but I found a simple fix for the extra new line, by using RemoveAt(list.Count - 1). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If your need is that simple, don't use a REGEX.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
   string line = sr.ReadLine();
   while( line != null ){
     if( line.StartsWith( "PA11" ) ){
        string[] parts = line.Split( " " );
        List<string> parameterList = new List<string>(parts);

        foreach (string s in parameterList)
                listBox1.Items.Add(s);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. A couple of things. First, rather than using a `StreamReader`, just use `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file))`. Second, why create a `List<string>` from the `parts` array when you can just write `foreach (var s in parts)`?

Comment: This code does not seem to be working for me. When I run it, the program just freezes.

Comment: I was lazily using the existing code, the main point was to use the .StartsWith(..) method instead of a regex.

Comment: @almostProgramming: The reason it freezes is because it never reads more than one line. Add this line: `line = sr.ReadLine();` at the end of the loop--just after the closing brace of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use string.split?   string[] parts = line.split("PA11")..
you can reinsert the demimater back into each part.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it creates an empty [0] element is there is probably whitespace (newline) at the beginning  of the string.
The below will work, code tested here-> http://www.ideone.com/tsOlI  (I'm no .NET expert)

string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, @"`(?=(?<!^\s*)PA11)`");

**Expanded:**

```
(?=          # look ahead, we're at the first 'PA11'
    (?<!^\s*)     # before its ok, there can't be '^\s*' before us
    PA11          # ok, this 'PA11' is good to split
)            # end look ahead
```

Beware that if there is anything other than whitespace before the first PA11,
it will create a [0] element with that block.

It could be done a little more meaningfull in a *match all* context with something like this:

`(?:^\s*|(?<=\n))\s*(PA11.*?)(?=\n+PA11|$)`
use single line modifier or change `.*?` to `[\S\s]*?`

It will only match from beginning of block to before the next beginning (or end of string) 
and strips residual boundry whitespace characters.